# Hacer una consulta dinamica phql

Tags: php, phalcon

Hola tengo una función con la cual quiero obtener datos de acuerdo a unos filtros de busqueda.
Dicha funcion puede o no contener algunos datos dependiendo de la busqueda que realice el usuario.

```
// FILTRO HOTEL
if(isset($hotels) and $hotels !="0" ){
    //$hotels = explode(",", $hotels);
    $consultaHotel = " AND r.clave_hotel_choice IN (:hotels:) ";
    $parameters['hotels'] = ['hotels' => $hotels];
}else{
    $consultaHotel = "";
}

// FILTRO ESTADO
if(isset($status) and $status !="0" ){
    //$status = explode(",", $status);
    $consultaStatus = " AND r.estado IN (:estado:) ";
    $parameters['estado'] = ['estado' => $status] ;
}else{
    $consultaStatus = "";
}

$sql = "SELECT g.*, r.*, gs.* FROM $this->modelClass r
INNER JOIN $this->modelGroupClass g ON g.iddef_group = r.iddef_group
INNER JOIN $this->modelReservationGuestClass gs ON r.iddef_reservation = gs.iddef_reservation
WHERE r.iddef_reservation != 0 ".$consultaStatus .$consultaHotel;

$dataDetalle = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($sql)->execute([$parameters])->toArray();
```

Al hacer esto me regresa un error que es asi:

> {
> "error": true,
> "message": "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"
> }

cabe mencionar que los datos pueden llegar uno o varios registros separados por coma para la busqueda es decir por ejemplo: status => 1,2

Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estás definiendo correctamente los parámetros a enviar.

Cuando aplicas el filtro:

```
$parameters['hotels'] = ['hotels' => $hotels];
```

En caso de funcionar, estarías creando un arreglo dentro de otro, quedando algo como:

```
[
    'hotels' => [
        'hotels' => $hotels
    ]
];
```

Y realmente solo necesitas un arreglo con pares `clave => valor` usando `$parameters['hotels'] = $hotels;` y el resultado sería con el formato que requiere PHQL:

```
[
    'hotels' => $hotels
];
```

Luego, al ejecutar la consulta `execute([$parameters])` con los corchetes estás colocando todo en un nuevo arreglo.

```
// Definir parámetros como arreglo vacío
$parameters = [];
// FILTRO HOTEL
if(isset($hotels) and $hotels !="0" ){
    //$hotels = explode(",", $hotels);
    $consultaHotel = " AND r.clave_hotel_choice IN (:hotels:) ";
    // Agregar solo el elemento correspondiente
    $parameters['hotels'] = $hotels;
}else{
    $consultaHotel = "";
    // No se agregan parámetros
    // Pero la variable ya está definida para evitar errores
}

// FILTRO ESTADO
if(isset($status) and $status !="0" ){
    //$status = explode(",", $status);
    $consultaStatus = " AND r.estado IN (:estado:) ";
    $parameters['estado'] = ['estado' => $status] ;
}else{
    $consultaStatus = "";
}

$sql = "SELECT g.*, r.*, gs.* FROM $this->modelClass r
INNER JOIN $this->modelGroupClass g ON g.iddef_group = r.iddef_group
INNER JOIN $this->modelReservationGuestClass gs ON r.iddef_reservation = gs.iddef_reservation
WHERE r.iddef_reservation != 0 ".$consultaStatus .$consultaHotel;

// No encerrar la variable entre corchetes    
$dataDetalle = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($sql)->execute($parameters)->toArray();
```

Comment: Gracias, asi ya no me marca errores pero no me trae ningún dato.